# Java Initialize String array

Tags: java

Can I initialize string array like this

```
String arr=new String[];/* initialize the array */
```

Comment: Why not trying yourself?

Comment: you forget the size of that array and try it on yourself

Comment: No you can't, hence it doesn't compile. You should specify array dimension (length)

Answer (score 8):

No, because you need to tell the compiler how big you want the array to be. Remember that arrays have a fixed size after creation. So any of these are okay, to create an empty array:

```
String[] array = {};
String[] array = new String[0];
String[] array = new String[] {};
```

Admittedly an empty array is rarely useful. In many cases you'd be better off using an `ArrayList<String>` instead. Of course sometimes you *have* to use an array - in order to return a value from a method, for example.

If you want to create an array of a specific length and then initialize it later, you can specify the length:

```
String[] array = new String[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    array[i] = String.valueOf(i); // Or whatever
}
```

One nice feature of empty arrays is that they're immutable - you can't change the length, and because then length is 0 there are no elements to mutate. So if you *are* going to regularly use an empty array of a particular type, you can just create it once:

```
private static final String[] EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY = {};
```

... and reuse that everywhere.

Comment: missing square brackets on the left hand side of assignment operator.

Comment: `String[] array = new String[0] {};` this doesn't work now, but I wonder if it really worked with an older Java version.

Comment: @Tom: Hmm. Not sure why I had that. Will fix...

Comment: Is "empty array" the same as "zero length array"? I guess it's analogous to "empty string", but "empty" to me seems to indicate something with space but no entries, whereas a zero-length array doesn't even have space.

Comment: @Sahuagin: They're the same thing. An array of length 1 has 1 entry, regardless of its value.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that. It will produce compile error
  you shoud write

```
String[] arr=new String[4];  //you should declared it sized
```

or

```
String[] arr={"asgk"};
```

or

```
String[] arr=new String[]{};
```